# reportDocument.ExportToDisk error when exporting Crystal Report to Word

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am getting an error from my C# code when I try to export a Crystal Report to Word using `reportDocument.ExportToDisk`.

It crashes on this line:

```
reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, WordPath);
```

The complete error message is this:

> Logon failed.
>   Details: IM002:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   Error in File C:\Users\disaia\AppData\Local\Temp\DisplayLabel {47AE6D67-D16D-4FB9-BE38-7F7B300D83C0}.rpt:
>   Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.

WordPath = `"C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\ShoeReport\\admin\\DOC\\1_DisplayStickers.doc"` for my local machine.

This code runs just fine on our production server, but it crashes on our development server or my local development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is not set correctly on the development server and the development machine . If you are using ODBC check the DSN

Comment: I can view the report with the right data when I click the "Main Report Preview" tab.  Doesn't this mean the DSN is set up correctly?

Comment: I found the problem.  IIS has a 'Write' setting that was not checked.